# How to troubleshoot Topshelf (suspect it may be Nlog)

Tags: nlog, topshelf

Hi I'm trying to use TopShelf (I'm trying to use NLog with it). It works OK in the console but the service won't start. I get a error:

"A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the Service Name service to connect."

How do I find out what the underlying error is. Or is that the best level of detail.
I suspect it is something to do with NLog but I'm struggling to know how to use it in a live service context. Can anyone offer perhaps a high level explanation what needs to be done with Nlog regarding

Permissions of the service
Referencing the nlog.config (i.e. ensure the service can read it)
Using Nlog with the UseNlog class

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the internal logging of NLog so that it's more clear what the error is.

in nlog.config

```xml
<nlog internalLogFile="c:\log.txt" internalLogLevel="Trace">
   <targets>
      <!-- target configuration here -->
   </targets>
   <rules>
      <!-- log routing rules -->
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

or in C#

```cs
// enable internal logging to a file
InternalLogger.LogFile = "c:\\log.txt";

// set internal log level
InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Trace;
```